# Issue with \pagecolor from xcolor

Tags: color

After I updated texlive today, I noticed that `\pagecolor` from `xcolor` no longer works as it should. I tested this with lualatex, xelatex and pdflatex, but only xelatex gave the expected result (dark pagecolor). Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{Pagecolor}{RGB}{18,18,18} % Dark gray
\definecolor{Textcolor}{RGB}{225,225,225} % Light gray
\pagecolor{Pagecolor}
\color{Textcolor}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, somehow two stray braces ended up in the files and so hide the new code. I will make an update.

Comment: ah no the problem are not stray braces. The hooks are not initialized. Add `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\relax}` to your document as a work around until I updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed. With a current xcolor the page color is correct again.